# Python prints result as '7\xe6\x9c\x8810\xe6\x97\xa5', but I want '7月10日'

Tags: python, unicode, printing

I fetched a web page, which contains Japanese, but when I print it to the console I didn't get the output as **`7月10日`**. Instead, it prints: `7\xe6\x9c\x8810\xe6\x97\xa5`

What should I do?

Comment: Are you on Python 3? If so you are probably printing a byte object. In my experience, at least on Windows, Python throws if you try to print an unmappable character.

Comment: my guess is that your console is not able to print UTF-8... (What type of console are we talking about)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output you get is correct. That is the UTF-8 representation of the japanese string. The problem is the console itself that it doesn't understand UTF-8. If you write that string in a file and open it with an editor that does understand UTF-8 you'll see the content as you would expect. You could also try to change the console's encoding to UTF-8.

Edit: You could also try something along:

```
print '7\xe6\x9c\x8810\xe6\x97\xa5'.decode('utf-8')
```

But whether this works depends on the whether the console encoding supports japanese characters. If for example the console's encoding is 'ISO Latin-1' than it won't work...

I suggest you read: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: No. The console configured to use some 8-bit encoding wouldn't escape octets above 7-bit ASCII to hex digits.

Comment: thank you. i use ide of pycharm, when i print a string(print a[1]), it can show japanese,when print a dictionary(print a), it doesn't.

Comment: @Tadeusz The console might use UTF-16 in which case the string is invalid.

Comment: In Python, when you fetch a webpage, Python does not automatically decode the text for you, like it does otherwise. All my webpage fetches look like this: `try:
               page = request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8'); 
          except error.HTTPError as e:
               _print('HTTPError:', e)` (Pardon the lack of formatting)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#examples : `Note that urlopen returns a bytes object. This is because there is no way for urlopen to automatically determine the encoding of the byte stream it receives from the http server. In general, a program will decode the returned bytes object to string once it determines or guesses the appropriate encoding.` `As the python.org website uses utf-8 encoding as specified in it’s meta tag, we will use the same for decoding the bytes object: >>> f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
>>> print(f.read(100).decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: When you print a string, you get just the contents of the string. When you print a dictionary, there isn't a 'natural' string form for that to take, so Python falls back to printing the Python code representation (`repr()`) of the dictionary, including the surrounding quotes and all. The `repr()` for strings in Python 2 uses backslash-escapes for non-ASCII characters because printing them literally on consoles can be highly problematic (especially on Windows).